# adding two legends to an image.plot

Tags: r, plot, maps, legend-properties

I am a new R user and I need some help to setup a secondary legend for a map.

Description:
 I plotted a map using the image.plot function in the fields Library with x and y axes indicating the coordinates and a color scale with a legend andicating the attitude as describedd by the code line below:

> image.plot(x,y,z,col=greyscale,legend.mar=8.5,xlab="",ylab="",main="Lambert2étendu")

Problem:

I added points the the map indicating the locations of two types of recievers with different color and cex for each type. and I want to add a legend under the map to describe each coloration signification

Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `legend` for a secondary legend. Increase the bottom `mar`gin and add legend with negative `inset`, i.e. move away from plot:

```
library(fields)
x<- 1:10
y<- 1:15
z<- outer( x,y,"+") 

# plot with extra margin at bottom (7)
par(mar=c(7,4,4,2)+0.1)
image.plot(x,y,z,col=gray.colors(10), xlab='', ylab='') 

# create points
xp = sample(1:10,size=5)
yp = sample(1:10,size=5)
points(xp,yp,pch=21,bg=1:2,cex=1:2)

# add legend (might have to change inset if you resize the plot)
legend('bottom', horiz=T, legend=paste('type', 1:2), pt.cex=1:2, pch=21, pt.bg=1:2, xpd=NA, inset=c(0,-1..))
```

[image: double legend]

Comment: exactly what I need but when i do the same this error appear:
Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : 
  font face -2147483648 not supported for font family 'HersheySerif'

Comment: I appreciated the use of inset with a negative value.  Useful tip.  Thanks.